# Exchange Server 2013: after update from CU16 to CU17, several services fail to start and/or show status UnHealthy

Tags: exchange, service, exchange-2013, health

After updating from Cummulative Update 16 to Cummulative Update 17, I'm having problems with my Exchange 2013 Services

**How can I troubleshoot:**

1. Failure of service to start on a fresh reboot? (Starting the service manually works without issue).
2. Some services (`HealthSet`) show as `UnHealthy` (via Exchange Management Shell, `Get-HealthReport -identity servername`) either after a fresh reboot or after I start them manually (see issue 1).

**Symptoms:**

After fresh reboot, the following services don't start (but I can start them myself manually with no errors):

```
Microsoft Exchange Transport
Microsoft Exchange Transport Delivery
Microsoft Exchange Transport Submission
Microsoft Exchange IMAP4
Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 BackEnd
Microsoft Exchange FrontEnd Transport
Microsoft Exchange Health Manager
```

After manually starting the above services, the following `HealthSet` show as `UnHealthy`:

```
HealthSet: AD , AlertValue: UnHealthy
HealthSet: IMAP , AlertValue: UnHealthy
HealthSet: IMAP.Proxy , AlertValue: UnHealthy
HealthSet: HubTransport , AlertValue: UnHealthy
HealthSet: Transport , AlertValue: UnHealthy
HealthSet: FrontEndTransport , AlertValue: UnHealthy
```

After some hours of uptime, only this `HealthSet` continues to show as `UnHealthy`:

```
HealthSet: AD , AlertValue: UnHealthy
```

(`UM.CallRouter` and `UM.Protocol` also show as `UnHealthy`, but since I don't use Unified Messaging, I don't think this matters)

Comment: Did you maybe updated the .net framework to a [unsupported](http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/articles/exchange/384-net-framework-4-7-released-but-not-yet-supported-on-exchange-2016.html) version like 4.7?

Comment: No I did not update .net

Comment: Anyway, after a couple of days all `HealthSets` are now showing as `Healthy`.  I didn't change anything so ... I have no idea.

Comment: OK, this is weird, I just had to restart my Exchange Server today, and after a reboot (and after waiting for over 2 hours) the ONLY `Microsoft Exchange` services that started correctly are `Microsoft Exchange Diagnostics` and `Microsoft Exchange Search Host Controller`.  That's 2 out of like 27 Microsoft Exchange services that should be running...

Comment: Argh, and after another reboot, most services have started correctly, except: `FrontEnd Transport`, `IMAP4`, `MailBox Transport Delivery`, `Transport` and `Unified Messaging`.  `Get-HealthReport` shows `ActiveSync`, `FreeBusy`, `BitLockerDeployment`, `Transport`, `Places`, `POP`, `PushNotifications`, `FfoWebService`, `FfoWebStore`, `OutlookMapiHttp`, `AntiMalWare`, `FfoCentralAdmin`, and `StreamingOptics` as `AlertValue`: `Unknown` and `Search` as `Degraded`

Comment: Did you see something useful in the eventlog?